# Invisible ILLEGAL TOKEN error in Chrome and IE9, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, browser, syntax-error

Check out this HTML-page: http://ecmazing.com/wtf.html

In Chrome and IE9 an Illegal token / invalid character error is thrown.

The source code of that page:

```
<!doctype html>            

<html>    
    <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8">    
        <title>WTF</title>    
    </head>    
    <body>    
        <script>    
            var foo = 'bar';​    
        </script>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

What is going on here? There is no syntax error in the above code.

Answer (score 4):

If you select `bar` and use shift + right arrow to contineously select the next character, you'll see there is an invisible one behind the `;`.

```
"​".charCodeAt(0) === 8203
```

It [appears](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) to be a "zero width space". I wonder why that character exists apart from causing frustration.

Comment: How do I select `bar`? Is that in Chrome's developer tools?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Well I mean on this very webpage, in your question code, using a double-click with the mouse.